# Ionic cordova windows build fails

Tags: windows, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to build my ionic-angular app on windows platform

> VS 2017 professional installed with all reqd tools/sdks

getting the below error

PS C:\Users\jmzw\GIT\OMW\omw> cordova build windows
MSBuild v4.0 is not supported, aborting.
(node:13032) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AppPackages doesn't exists
(node:13032) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13032) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
PS C:\Users\jmzw\GIT\OMW\omw>

--------ionic info---------

C:\Users\jmzw\GIT\OMW\omw>ionic info

cli packages: (C:\Users\jmzw\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : windows 5.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node : v8.10.0
npm  : 5.6.0
OS   : Windows 10
```

can some one help here

Comment: Any thoughts ??

Comment: This is fixed, follow the bellow steps

Comment: This is fixed, follow the bellow steps
1. cd ionic app dir.
2. ionic cordova platform add windows
3. ionic prepare platform windows
4. Add below section in config.xml
<platform name="windows">
        <preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
    </platform>
 
5. open the ' CordovaApp.sln ' from appdir/platforms/windows/ in VS 2013/2015/2017 [Assuming you have the Visual studio set up for cordova build]
6. build it from  VS